# What is the best practice in creating scheduling calendar in php and html?

Tags: php, html

I want to create a website with an scheduling calendar.

My first idea is to use some free calendar template or download some free scheduling calendar. Then in my scheduling form, when someone request for an schedule, I will get the date he/she input and save it into the database then show it to the scheduling calendar.

But someone told me that, in my database, I should create a calendar table.

Which is the best way around?

The first one with only one table for schedule on my database or the second one with two tables for schedule and calendar?

I hope you get my idea.

Answer (score 0):

It could be first one. One of option is to keep data by day of year.
you can draw your own calendar by counting day of year

```
actual day of yaer - date('z') + 1; //+ 1 because it is an array it starts from 0
```

then you can get number of days in each month

```
cal_days_in_month
```

and loop it  x 12 with

```
<a href = "task.php?dy=&dayofyear&year=$year">here will be day of month with css style so it looks like calendar field</a>
```

your i++ will bee number of days in month of course.
Keep records in database by year and day of year. you can do so much things this way